# How to work on a project that needs sudo privilege

Tags: makefile

I am trying to add image support to [slock](https://tools.suckless.org/slock/), a screen lock utility from suckless.org. But slock needs root privilege to run. I didn't have problem with it when I was using it because I just did `make && sudo make install`. But now that I constantly need to edit, build and check, I can't figure out how to work on this project.

My workflow has been like

```
make
sudo chown root:root ./slock
sudo chmod u+s ./slock
./slock
```

I don't know how else to go about doing this. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `test` recipe to your `Makefile`

```
test: ./slock
    sudo chown root:root $<
    sudo chmod u+s $<
    $<
```

You might even want to make it the default target which is executed when you call `make` with no target arguments. Your workflow would simply become

```
 make
 make
 make
 ...
```

until you are satisfied with the result